# Duplicate key error but no entry with same values to be found when inserting data through LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, linq

I'm using C# Linq to interact with an MSSQL database. I have a problem where I sometime get the error message:

> "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_clustered_key_name'. Cannot
>   insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.table_name'. The statement has
>   been terminated."

When I try to add information to the database. When the error occurs I do an sql query with the values I try to add, in the MSSQL Management Studio and there doesn't seem to be an entry in the table.

So my question is if anyone has a clue about what the issue might be here. Some additional information follows.

The code I run (the error occurs at `SaveChanges`) is the following:

```
table_name table_name_instance = new table_name();
...
fill in values of fps
...

context.table_name.AddObject(fps);

context.SaveChanges();
```

I've also added a check if values of col1, col2, col3, col3 already exist in database so I definetly won't add duplicate entries. Since I'm not sure if the add is delayed and the check return that a duplicate entry already exist I've stored added values in a local container as well just to be sure, but I still get the error when calling SaveChanges().

The definition of my table with the clustered key for which the error is reported follows. Col1 through col4 is all Guid:s that are Foreign keys to other tables.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table_name](
    [col1] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [col2] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [col3] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [col4] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_forbandsscenariokrav] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [col1] ASC,
    [col2] ASC,
    [col3] ASC,
    [col4] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I've seen many similar questions but haven't found an answer that seem to apply to my situation.

Additional info, I'm using MSSQL server 2008 R2 under Win 7 64-bit as well as:

- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 10.50.1600.1
- Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 6.1.7601.17514
- Microsoft MSXML 3.0 5.0 6.0
- Microsoft Internet Explorer 8.0.7601.17514
- Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0.50727.5448
- Operating System 6.1.7601

---

**Updated**
When I instead use the Create function like this:

```
table_name table_name_instance = Createtable_name(col_val, col2_val,...);
context.table_name.AddObject(fps);
context.SaveChanges();
```

It seems to work just fine. Does that give any hint on why my first solution with new wasn't working even though I filled in every column value, not accepting null with a value?

Comment: Perhaps the insert you're doing contains 2 duplicate key values.  The entire insert will be aborted, so you won't see either in the table.  You can use `SQL Profiler` to see exactly what LINQ is doing.

Comment: Have you tried running the [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) against the database to see what `INSERT` statement gets generated from your application?

Comment: The thing is that I only add one entry at a time. I do a AddObject for each entry, then I do a SaveChanges(). I'll have a look at SQL Profiler and see if that show something interesting.

Comment: What makes you think that you are not inserting a row that already exists?

Comment: At least for this debugging session, you should try a query on the table with the same Primary Key values and check wether you get a record back and then decide if you need a INSERT or UPDATE.

Comment: Seems like the combination of guid values you are trying to insert already exists in the table as you said all the guids are foreign keys from other tables. Run SQL profiler to know what the values are and why it is throwing an error.

Comment: @jeroenh when I get the exception i Visual Studio I take the guid:s from the values LINQ is trying to insert into the database. Then I use them to do a select in the same table but it return no result, i.e there is no duplicate entry in the database.

Comment: Oh, the SQL Profiler doesn't appears to be included in the express version of SQL Server 2008 so that seem to be a dead end. =/

Answer (score 0):

See whether this SQL statement works on your SQL Server

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_name]
       ([col1]
       ,[col2]
       ,[col3]
       ,[col4])
VALUES
       (NEWID(),
       NEWID(),
       NEWID(),
       NEWID())
GO
```

If it does then that means the Guid you are creating from your app are duplicating. Before inserting data in your database check whether the primary key you want to insert exists in the table. You have to do this for each column as every column is a PK.